# Design a datastructure to support stack operations and to find minimum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

Interview question: Design a data structure which has the following features

- push the data
- pops the last inserted data [LIFO]
- Gives the minimum

All of the above operations should have a complexity of `O(1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack with find-min/find-max more efficient than O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134129/stack-with-find-min-find-max-more-efficient-than-on)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by maintaining two stacks

`stack` - do the usual push and pop operations on this stack.

`minStack` - this stack is used to get the min ele in the stack in `O(1)` time. At any point the top element of this stack will be the min of all the elements in the stack.

```
push( item a) 
    // push the element on the stack.
    stack.push(a)   

    // find the min of the ele to be pushed and the ele on top of minStack.
    if(minStack.isEmpty()) 
        min = a
    else
        min = Min(a,minStack.top())

    // push the min ele on the minStack.
    minStack.push(min) 
end push


pop()
    // pop and discard
    minStack.pop() 

    // pop and return
    return stack.pop() 
end pop


findMin()
    return minStack.top()
end findMin
```

In the above solution every time an element is pushed on stack, there is a corresponding push on `minStack`. So at any time the number of elements in stack and `minStack` are same. We can slightly optimize it by pushing an element onto `minStack` only if the element is smaller then the present min.

```
push( item a) 
    // push the element on the orginal stack.
    stack.push(a)   

    if(minStack.isEmpty())
            // if minStack is empty push.
            minStack.push(a) 
    // else push only if the element is less than or equal to the present min.
    else if(a <= minStack.top()) 
        minStack.push(a)
end push

pop()
    // pop from the stack
    ele = stack.top()     
    if(minStack.top() == ele)
            // pop only if the top element is ele.
        minStack.pop() 

    // return the popped element.
    return ele 
end pop
```

Comment: We can. We can eliminate minStack and do its push/pop on the main stack itself, but technically it will not be a stack anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, your data structure should contain two stacks.  One should function as normal; the other one only contains the last minimum element seen.  When you push an element, if it is less than /equal to the second stack's top (or the stack is empty), push it on the second stack as well.  When you pop an element, if it is equal to the second stack's top, pop the second stack too.

The minimum at any time is the top of the second stack.

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually asking for a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

PriorityQueue is a classical case (implementation of Heap). See `java.util.PriorityQueue`

I wish there was an easy way online to reference to Java language source code where I can see and refer to the implementation of PriorityQueue class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more creative solution without using an auxiliary stack.

Supposing that we are going to push a number *value* into a stack with minimum number *min*. If *value* is greater than or equal to the *min*, it is pushed directly into data stack. If it is less than *min*, we push 2**value* -*min*, and update *min* as *value* since a new minimum number is pushed.

How about to pop? We pop it directly if the top of data stack (it is denoted as *top*) is greater than or equal to *min*. Otherwise the number *top* is not the real pushed number. The real pushed number is stored as *min*. After the current minimum number is popped, we need to restore the previous minimum number, which is 2**min*-*top*.

Now let us demonstrate its correctness of this solution. When *value* is greater than or equal to *min*, it is pushed into data stack direct without updating *min*. Therefore, when we find that the top of data stack is greater than or equal to *min*, we can pop directly without updating *min*. However, if we find *value* is less then *min*, we push 2**value*-*min*. We should notice that 2**value*-*min* is less than *value*. Then we update current *min* as *value*. Therefore, the new top of data stack (*top*) is less than the current *min*. Therefore, when we find that the top of data stack is less then *min*, the real top (real pushed number *value*) is stored in *min*. After we pop the top of data stack, we have to restore the previous minimum number. Since *top* = 2**value*-previous *min* and *value* is current *min*, pervious *min* is 2*current *min* - *top*.

The C++ sample code is shown below:

```
template <typename T> class StackWithMin {
public:
    StackWithMin(void) {}
    virtual ~StackWithMin(void) {}

    T& top(void);
    void push(const T& value);
    void pop(void);
    const T& min(void) const;

private:
    std::stack<T>   m_data;     // data stack, to store numbers
    T               m_min;      // minimum number
};

template <typename T> void StackWithMin<T>::push(const T& value) {
    if(m_data.size() == 0) {
        m_data.push(value);
        m_min = value;
    }
    else if(value >= m_min) {
        m_data.push(value);
    }
    else {
        m_data.push(2 * value - m_min);
        m_min = value;
    }
}

template <typename T> void StackWithMin<T>::pop() {
    assert(m_data.size() > 0);

    if(m_data.top() < m_min)
        m_min = 2 * m_min - m_data.top();

    m_data.pop();
}

template <typename T> const T& StackWithMin<T>::min() const {
    assert(m_data.size() > 0);

    return m_min;
}

template <typename T> T& StackWithMin<T>::top() {
    T top = m_data.top();
    if(top < m_min)
        top = m_min;

    return top;
}
```

This solution is borrowed from [my blog](http://codercareer.blogspot.com/2011/09/no-02-stack-with-function-min.html), and my book "[Coding Interviews: Questions, Analysis & Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247614)".