# Deque with a max api?

Tags: data-structures

Implementing a queue with a `max()` API so that `push()`, `pop()`, and `max()` all work in (amortized) O(1) is a [known solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054415/get-min-max-in-o1-time-from-a-queue). Is there a known solution for implementing a double ended queue with the same `max()` API which is faster than O(n)? Can it be proven that it's impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 100% possible to have a `deque` with an `O(1)` max api.

A `deque` can be [implemented from two stacks](https://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/2_5_Building_Deque_from_Two.html). While there's some additional business logic in keeping the `deque` balanced, the idea is fairly simple. Imagine two stacks facing opposite directions joined together. From this structure you can pop and append to both sides.

It's possible to create a stack that has a constant time `get_max()` or `get_min()`. Each time you push onto the stack push onto it two things - `(value, current_max)`. You can calculate the `current_max` in constant time by comparing the `current_max` in previous element to the current `value`. The result of `get_max()` will always be the `current_max` of the top of the stack.

If you implement a `deque` from two stacks that have the `get_max()` api, to get max of the deque, you only have to call `get_max()` for both stacks and return the bigger value.

Comment: Great idea! I guess in this case although `get_max()` is O(1), maintaining a deque with two stacks requires O(1) amortized cost since when the either one is empty you will have to do O(n) work.